# I need help with postfix

Tags: postfix

I am trying to use postfix in order to send out e-mails when i have alerts on my checkmk. My issue is that after going through 50+ guides + videos online *nothing ever works!!*

My understanding is that some changes were made a month + ago which removed the option of sending emails from your pc (which was an option before that) and logging with your gmail account through a simple pass and username in order to reduce the mail spam.

So now in order to send an email you have to have your own registered domain registered host and a ton of other things that I have 0 concept of.

Is there a way to set up postfix to actually work or is that no longer a viable option and if there is a way how the hell is that achievable?

Here is additional info, this is my `main.cf` file:

```
myhostname=checkmk.local
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
recipient_delimiter = +

compatibility_level = 2


#smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
#smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
inet_protocols = ipv4

smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
relay_domains = gmail.com
```

With this configuration I am getting 'username and password not accepted' as I mentioned above google (and not only) made some changes where you can't log in with simple username+password anymore. To be more precise here is a link with additional info:
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials

I also went for a simple setup without trying to log in with gmail account at which point I get the 'bounced' error:

```
Host or domain name not found.
Name service error for name=ns.local type=AAAA:
Host not found
```

My understanding is that I have to have a domain name where ns.local (in this case) has AAAA record which I have to create.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't provide much info that anyone can use to help. Here are some things you probably would want to clarify in your post (and remove the rants please): 1) What changed a month ago? 2) Were you using postfix as an SMTP relay server (using Google SMTP)? 3) Which errors are you getting that could help anyone understand what's wrong? 4) Please come up with more details yourself that may help...

Comment: Google has been rolling out 2 Factor Authorisation for its email service which might be the recent change you are referring to? This has been ongoing for some time but perhaps has just been rolled out for you. However all that is needed for this with PostFix and friends is an App Password that is generated from your Google account's Security settings: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: I edited my post above and I didn't answer the question ''What changed a month ago?'' As I mentioned a month or so ago from what I have gathered in order to try and fight the huge influx of spam of e-mails some steps have been taken which remove the option of simple logging in with a username and password using programs like postfix and using annonymouse e-mails where the sender of the e-mail can't be contacted (aka is not registed to a domain) because those types of communication are considered 'not secure'. Honestly I don't care how or what method I can use as long as there is someone who...

Comment: can provide me with an example of actual working setup for postfix which does not require you to have a domain name with where you have to create AAAA or other records etc. There are plenty of 'setups' out and about for postfix except none of them seem to be working unless you have a registered domain name (And even that I am not sure about since i can't test that option).

Answer (score 0):

> Google has been rolling out 2 Factor Authorisation for its email
> service which might be the recent change you are referring to? This
> has been ongoing for some time but perhaps has just been rolled out
> for you. However all that is needed for this with PostFix and friends
> is an App Password that is generated from your Google account's
> Security settings: support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833 –
> andrew.46

This was the answer! After playing around with it and setting up 2 FA i could start sending emails to anywhere and anything! Thank you andrew.46 for pointing me in the right direction! May you live long and prosper!

Comment: And may you live long and prosper too!